# Time complexity and content free evaluation

Tags: time-complexity

I am having trouble answering the question below:

"Explain why the statement, “The running time of algorithm A is at least O(n^2)”, is content-free."

The statement apparently does not give any information on the running time of A but if A = T(n), then T(n) >= O(n^2). Doesn't this at the very least tell us that A runs bigger than n^2?

Comment: I think the question aims to point out that for a constant running time $c$ you have $c \in \mathcal{O}(1) \subseteq \mathcal{O}(n^2)$. So you might interpret the statement as "There is a running time in $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ that is a lower bound for $\mathcal{A}$'s running time." However, as a constant running time is suitable to select from $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ this is a completely trivial statement that does not provide any insights about $\mathcal{A}$'s actual running time.

Comment: @ttnick Consider turning your comment into an answer :)

Comment: @Steven Absolutely. I initially started writing a comment because I did not understand the question and was asking for more context. But now, we have to clean up the comments here, I unfortunately do not know the protocol for that here. I did not want to just remove the comment and let yours left alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [Steven](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/6759/steven), I turned my comment into a full answer.

I think the question aims to point out that for a constant running time $c$ you have $c \in \mathcal{O}(1) \subseteq \mathcal{O}(n^2)$.

So you might interpret the statement in your exercise as *"There is a running time in $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ that is a lower bound for $\mathcal{A}$'s running time."*

However, as a constant running time is suitable to select from $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ this is a completely trivial statement that does not provide any insights about $\mathcal{A}$'s actual running time.